# Is it possible to save pdf file in media library in Windows phone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to save a PDF file to the media library in Windows Phone 8? If it is, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media Library allows you to save Images. That's it. No PDFs and nothing else